# Spring security returns error, even when I entered valid data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring data, spring mvc, spring core, spring security, maven, tomcat, mysql.

I'm learning Spring Security and I'm trying to create an app (registration + login).

Registration is working, but login page returns error even when I enter valid data.

I don't know why it isn't working. Thanks for help!

My code:

```
repository
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("from User where username=:username")
    public User findByUserName(@Param("username")String username);

}

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>{

    @Query("from Role where name=:name")
    public Role findByRoleName(@Param("name")String name);
}


entity:

package com.myapp.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long rid;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(Long rid, String name) {
        super();
        this.rid = rid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getRid() {
        return rid;
    }

    public void setRid(Long rid) {
        this.rid = rid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role [rid=" + rid + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}

@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long uid;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable
    (name="users_roles",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="uid"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="rid"))
    private Collection<Role>roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Long uid, String username, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
        super();
        this.uid = uid;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(Long uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [uid=" + uid + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", roles=" + roles + "]";
    }

}


service:

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepo;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user =userRepo.findByUserName(username);

        if(user==null)
        {
            System.out.println("USER WAS NOT FOUND");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password");
        }
        System.out.println("USER REPO RETURN: L: "+user.getUsername()+" P: "+user.getPassword());


        System.out.println(user.getUsername()+ user.getPassword());


        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userDetails= new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.getRoles().stream().map(r->new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return userDetails;

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User findByUserName(String name) {
        return userRepo.findByUserName(name);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) 
    {
        User protectedUser=new User();
        Set<Role>roles=new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(roleRepo.findByRoleName("ROLE_EMPLOYEE"));
        protectedUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        protectedUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));      protectedUser.setRoles(roles);
        userRepo.save(protectedUser);
    }

}

public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService{

    public User findByUserName(String username);

    public void save(User user);
}


Config:

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    /*
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider ownProvider;
    */

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
        .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied-page");
    }


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }  


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService); 
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }   

}

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[] {WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.myapp"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
        .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator=new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        return validator;

    }

}


@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name=authentication.getName();
        String password=authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        System.out.println("CUSTOM AUTHENTICATION PROVIDER : NAME: "+name+" Password: "+password);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}



@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("\n\nIn customAuthenticationSuccessHandler\n\n");

        String userName = authentication.getName();

        System.out.println("userName=" + userName);

        User theUser = userService.findByUserName(userName);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user", theUser);

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/");
    }

}

controllers:

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/showMyLoginPage")
    public String showMyLoginPage()
    {
        return "login-page";
    }

}



@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/system")
    public String system()
    {
        return "system";
    }
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/showRegisterForm")
    public String showRegisterForm(Model model)
    {
        User user=new User();
        model.addAttribute(user);
        return "register-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveUser")
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user)
    {
        userService.save(user);
        return "register-confirmation";
    }

}
```

and jsp:

```
login:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/authenticateTheUser">

    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
    <i style="color:red;">Sorry! You entered invalid date.</i>
    </c:if>


    <p>User name: <input type="text" name="username"/> </p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </p>



    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form:form>

Register here! <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register/showRegisterForm" > Register now!</a>


</body>
</html>





register:

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register/saveUser" modelAttribute="user">

Name: <form:input path="username"/>

Password <form:password path="password"/>

<button type="submit">Register</button>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add error message?

Comment: I don't have any erorrs, just invalid username or password from spring security.

    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
    <i style="color:red;">Sorry! You entered invalid date.</i>
    </c:if>

Comment: I can't really see where in controller you handle input data from login form. Are you sure login is handled anywhere on server side?

Comment: In spring security I don't have to write code to handle it(right?). The Spring security doing it behind scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should read documentation here:
[Spring security on baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider)

And that quick fix may be to add in your

```
CustomAuthenticationProvider
```

in method

```
authenticate
```

some code like this:

```
if (shouldAuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem()) {

        // use the credentials
        // and authenticate against the third-party system
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
          name, password, new ArrayList<>());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

Because I understand that you never authenticate a user.

Comment: I'm using DaoAuthenticationProvider
@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService); 
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;